# How to pay with bitcoin using Stripe.js Elements and React?

Tags: reactjs, stripe.js, stripe-payments

Considering [bitcoin as payment method](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/bitcoin), is there a simple way, using [react-strip-element](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements), to display a form that enable bitcoin payment?

Has anyone already try it?

I already use [react-strip-element](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements) for VISA/Mastercard payment:

```
import { StripeProvider, Elements } from 'react-stripe-elements';

...

<StripeProvider apiKey={stripePublishableKey}>
    <Elements locale={locale}>
        <StripeForm paymentConfig={paymentConfig} dispatch={dispatch} buyerName="toget" />
    </Elements>
</StripeProvider >
...
```

My element `<SripeForm>` only returns, within a `<form>`, `<CardElement hidePostalCode style={cardStyle} />` and a submit button.

I don't know if this `CardElement` can be used for bitcoin payment or if I must use another React Stripe Element.

Any help or experiences with Stripe bitcoin payment is welcome.

#### Edit

[react-strip-element](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements) Team gave an [answer to this question](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/issues/117):

> We don't currently have any Elements for bitcoin. You can either use Stripe Checkout, or build your own UI and use Stripe.js v3 to create bitcoin Sources.

So only one solution now: a custom React implementaton using Stripe Checkout. I'll post it here if enough time is left to me to implement it :).